# How can I display a single record in 2 rows by using Yii CGridView?

Tags: yii, frameworks

I am using CGridView in Yii, how can I display a single record in 2 lines?

Basically I want to show a record details in 1st row of table and on other row I want to display its summary, I tried it with div and css but can't get proper results, is anyone there who can help me in this case?

I am using like this:

```
<?php 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'bidding-grid',
'itemsCssClass' => 'data-default',
'dataProvider'=>$model,
'summaryText' => '',
'columns'=>array(
    'people_detail_for_bid.Person' => array(
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'name'=>'people_detail_for_bid.Person',
                        'value'=>'Yii::app()->Controller->createUserNameLink($data->people_detail_for_bid->PeopleFirstName." ".$data->people_detail_for_bid->PeopleLastName, $data->people_detail_for_bid->PeopleId).
                        "<br><span class=decriptionText>".$data->people_detail_for_bid->PeopleDesignation."</span>".
                        "<br><span class=decriptionText>".$data->people_detail_for_bid->PeopleEmail."</span>"',
                        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>200),
    ),
    'timeAgo' => array(
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'name'=>'timeAgo',
                        'value'=>'"<span class=decriptionText>".Yii::app()->Controller->_ago($data->PBPostedOn)."</sapn>"',
                        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>150),
    ),

),

)); 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After too much search .. and I tried with different ways now finally got a solution for this .. that solution is basically a kind of 2nd way to do anything not actual way .. but it works to me ..

```
.....
.....

    'timeAgo' => array(
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'name'=>'timeAgo',
                        'value'=>'"<span class=decriptionText>".Yii::app()->Controller->_ago($data->PBPostedOn)."</sapn></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"6\"><span class=decriptionText>".$data->PBSummary."</span>"',
                        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>150),
    ),

.....
.....
```

added some table tags on last column to close row and added another one.

hope it works for all ..

thanks ..

Answer (score 5):

I think the best and cleanest way to accomplish this is to create a new extension and extend it to CGridView, override the renderTableRow function like this:

```
/**
 * Renders a table body row.
 * @param integer $row the row number (zero-based).
 */
public function renderTableRow($row)
{
    if($this->rowCssClassExpression!==null)
    {
        $data=$this->dataProvider->data[$row];
        echo '<tr class="'.$this->evaluateExpression($this->rowCssClassExpression,array('row'=>$row,'data'=>$data)).'">';
    }
    else if(is_array($this->rowCssClass) && ($n=count($this->rowCssClass))>0)
        echo '<tr class="'.$this->rowCssClass[$row%$n].'">';
    else
        echo '<tr>';

    $colCtr = 0;
    foreach($this->columns as $column){
        $column->renderDataCell($row);
        $colCtr++;
    }

    echo "</tr>\n";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"$colCtr\">This is the summary row. </td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can customize what you are rendering in the columns, so if you want to show two different fields of your table in the same row, you have to create a function in your model:

```
public function customColumn()
{
    return $this->PeopleDesignation.'<br/>'.$this->PeopleEmail;
}
```

And then assign the method to the value of your column:

```
array(
    'type'=>'html',
    'value'=>'$data->customColumn()'
),
```

Cheers, Pablo.

Comment: Problem is @Shadman needs two custom rows, not 2 custom columns. And I imagine he wants to pull from multiple records, so the CGridView needs alternating customColumn assignments for each pair of rows, which is probably impossible.

Comment: yeh i need 2 rows in a single record and last row should containg summary of that record, and that must covers all columns .. like
<table>
<tr>
<td>1A</td>
<td>1B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>1C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2A</td>
<td>2B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>2C</td>
</tr>
</table>

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like 2 interleaved `CGridViews`. So you might try that, but I can't imagine it will work out well:

Overlay one `CGridView` over the other, with enough transparent space in each row for the other to display it's row, and ...

```
a. one `CGridView` table offset vertically by half a row height, *OR*
b. one table's row's text vertically top-aligned & the other bottom-aligned
```

But somehow I doubt that's a `CGridView` capability ;) And keeping the two in sync so they pagenate and scroll together would be darn near impossible. Sounds like you need to enhance CGridView or derive a new widget from `CGridView`. I wonder if JQuery has something to do this?